# Basis and dimension of null space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dimensional-analysis

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
 0&1  &2  &1  &1 \\ 
 1&0  &1  &1  &1 \\ 
 -1&2  &3  &1  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$ with the homogeneous system $A \mathbf{x}=\mathbf0$.

**Problem 1**

Find the parametric form for the solution set $N_{A}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^5 $ (null)

**Solution so far**

After row operations to find the augmented matrix in reduced echelon form, I get that the parametric form  with $s=x_3, t=x_4, k=x_5$ is
\begin{bmatrix}
-s-t-k\\ 
-2s-t-k\\ 
s\\ 
t\\ 
k\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
or
$\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
x_4\\ 
x_5\\
\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-2\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix}+k\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

**Problem 2 (Main)**

Specify a basis for the subspace $N_{A}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^5 $. What is the dimension of $N_{A}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^5 $?

**My Solution so far**

I am thinking the basis would just be the 3 vectors in my parametric form i.e

$\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-2\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and then I am thinking the dimension is just the cardinality of all the vectors in the specified solution space so 3?

I am certain this is wrong, though and I would like the approach for the main problem cleared up! Do I have to extend my solutions with the standard basis to get 5 vectors? Thanks!

edit: I have been taught that if i.e $\mathbb{R}^5$ then I would need to extend this system to 5 vectors. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those three vectors span $N_A$ and, since they are linearly independent, then are a basis of $N_A$. Therefore $\dim N_A=3$.

Comment: Do I not have to extend the basis to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^5$ and thus end up with a different dimension or is the dimension just the span i.e 3?

Comment: No. You are only required to find a basis of $N_A$, not to extend it a basis of $\Bbb R^5$.

Comment: Okay 1 more question. How would one write this out in a clear and formal way. for the first one; Specify the basis for the subspace $N_A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^5$ and the other problem; what is the dimension of the subspace $N_A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^5$? edit: In my answer I just went for my what I thought but would not be able to explain this in a clear way.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see what else do you need. Since those three vectors span $N_A$ and are linearly independent, the form a basis of $N_A$. And, since $N_A$ has a basis with three elements, its dimension is $3$.